# How do automatically change the status of a post after 30 days

Tags: database, laravel, model-view-controller, model

I have a classifieds website similar to Craigslist built with laravel.

There's a status column in my MySQL posts table and I want to be able to automatically change the status of all posts that is more than 30 days old  to "deleted "

So how do I do that in laravel.
There's no code here because I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: You will need a scheduler for that: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling

Comment: You could either have a timestamp field that specifies the date that you want it to be deleted (or use an existing one e.g. field+30 days is before now) and then scope you're queries to only show posts that timestamp is before now, or you could set up a [cron job](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling) to automatically go though and "delete" the posts.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the scheduler (docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling).

It allows you to perform cron tasks.

For instance, you could to something like that:

*You should read the documentation first because it contains a lot of useful information to understand the following code example.*

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
            YourModel::query()
                       ->where('created_at', '<', today()->subDays(30))
                       ->update(['your_status_column' => 'deleted');
        })->daily();
    }
}
```

Here we are updating the status of all `YourModel` that are created since more than 30 days to `deleted` (and we are doing it every days at midnight).

Of course you have to adapt the code to your model and column.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a command or job, and use task scheduling to automatically run the command and job you just created.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling